# Problem when printing a rectangle of a particular symbol in C

Tags: c, input, file-io, issue-tracking

I have recently been digging into the C language and decided to to try making a rectangle program.
However, I encountered a issue and cannot seem to find why it exists.

Each time I input a number of rows, columns and a symbol, it always prints 10 columns with the right symbol and amount of rows.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int rows;
int columns;
char symbol;

printf("\nEnter # of rows: ");
scanf("%d", &rows);

printf("Enter # of columns: ");
scanf("%d", &columns);

scanf("%c");

printf("Enter a symbol: ");
scanf("%c", &symbol);

for(int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= columns; j++)
    {
        printf("%c", symbol);    
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

And here is the output.

```
PS D:\CFolder\NestedLoops> cd "d:\CFolder\NestedLoops\" ; if ($?) { gcc NestedLoops.c -o 
NestedLoops } ; if ($?) { .\NestedLoops }

Enter # of rows: 3
Enter # of columns: 5
Enter a symbol: $
$$$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$$$
$$$$$$$$$$
PS D:\CFolder\NestedLoops>
```

No matter the column number I input, it always prints 10 columns.

As a side note, when I tried running the program but removing the symbol input it worked fine.

Comment: Omitting the second (target) argument from `scanf("%c");` causes *undefined behaviour*. The function will find **some** value which it will try to use as the target address. Here, the result seems to have corrupted a different variable.

Comment: There must be another agument, for example `char temp; scanf("%c", &temp);` or just  `scanf("%*c");` will read the newline but not attempt to store it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
scanf("%c");
```

`scanf` needs to consume an argument, since you are not providing any argument, my guess is that `scanf` is replacing the top value of the stack (`cols`) with the value of the newline (ASCII 10) left by the previous call to `scanf`, that's why it always prints 10 columns.

To consume the trailing newline, instead of an empty `scanf` use a space before the format specifier:

```
scanf(" %c", &symbol);
```

Now it should work.

Comment: I understand now that the `scanf()` function needs another arguement with it and the newline needs to be dealt in a different way. Thank you, the code runs normally now!